# Can one reference be assigned different values at different locations?

Tags: c++, reference

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int    x = 0;
    int    y = 1;

    int& z = x;
    z = x;
    z = y;

    cout << "\nx: " << x;
    cout << "\ny: " << y;

    cout << "\nz: " << z;
    return 0;
}
```

**

### EDIT:

**
This code returns 1 for all 3 cases. Shouldn't this be an error instead?

8.5.3 section of C++ standard says:

> A reference cannot be changed to refer to another object after
>   initialization. Note that initialization of a 2   reference is treated
>   very differently from assignment to it. Argument passing (5.2.2) and
>   function value   return (6.6.3) are initializations.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis Have edited the Q.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, in your code you aren't changing what `z` references, instead you're changing the contents of `z` (and in turn what it references, `x`).

You can see this with the following code:

```
x = 5;
cout << x;
cout << z;
```

Both `x` and `z` will have the value 5, since `z` remains a reference to `x`.

Comment: Q: Does z hold the "address" of x, and we aren't supposed to make z hold someone else's address?

Comment: No, z is an alias for x. If you print the address for both x and z, you'll see they're the same. If you want to hold the address of x, you would want z to be declared as a pointer. (If its a pointer, you can change the address it holds, effectively changing which variable it points to)

Comment: Because `&z` creates a **pointer** by taking the address of the variable. That isn't a valid lvalue, and `y` isn't of the right type anyway.

Answer (score 2):

```
z = x
z = y
```

does not change the reference but the value of `x`.

Answer (score 1):

No, that won't generate an error. As mentioned, assigning values to z is the same as assigning values to what it refers to, which in this case is x.

In this case, the standard mandates that z HAS to REFER to x. z cannot be made to refer to some other variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
    {   int    x = 0;        // Let x be located at memory 0x1234
        int    y = 1;        // Let y be located at memory 0x5678

        int& z = x;          //There is a variable call z that is a reference to x.  
//That is z refers to the same memory location and thus the same content.

        z = x;               //Set the contents of z to the content of x. 
//Since z is currently a reference to x this essentially does nothing.
        z = y;               //Set the contents of z to the content of y which is the 
//same as set the contents of memory 0x1234 to the contents of memory 0x5678. 

        cout << "\nx: " << x; //print the contents of memory 0x1234
        cout << "\ny: " << y; //print the contents of memory 0x5678

        cout << "\nz: " << z; //print the contents of memory 0x1234
        return 0;
    }
```

It is not giving you an error since you are not changing any memory pointers, but instead, their contents

Comment: Because you are trying to set an memory space variable (pointer) to a number (int). Try to add this code to help you understand pointers. (int *w = &z) which will set a (pointer) to a (pointer/ memory space of z). Then cout << w. which is the memory for w. and cout << *w. (which is the content within the memory space of w.